# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while using util Packages

Tags: java, file, exception, arraylist, out-of-memory

My problem statement:

There will be given set of words in a file (>5000 words). We need return a list of anagrams separated by comma(,) in each string(set of anagrams)
Eg: [alter,later, part,trap, elbow,below, listen,silent , tensil ]

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:462)
at FindAnagrams01.anagramsList(FindAnagrams01.java:25)
at FindAnagrams01.main(FindAnagrams01.java:7)
```

My code is :

```
  public static List<String> anagramsList(String filePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String str = br.readLine();
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>(10000);
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(10000);
    while(str != null) {
        char[] arr = new char[26];
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            arr[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;              
        }
        String ns = new String(arr);
        if(map.containsKey(ns)){
            map.get(ns).add(str);
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
            al.add(str);
            map.put(ns, al);
        }
    }
    br.close();
    result.addAll(map.values());
    String res[] = new String[10000];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        int isIntial = 0;
        for(String j : result.get(i)) {
            if ((result.get(i).size()) > 1) {
                if (isIntial == 0) {
                    res[i] = j;
                    isIntial = 1;
                }
                else
                    res[i] += "," + j;
            } 
        }
    }
    List<String> angrms = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        if (res[i] != null)
            angrms.add(res[i]);
    }
    return angrms;
}
```

Comment: `HashMap<String,arrayList<String>>` - what? Did you type this code in by hand? What is an `arrayList`? Any why are you presizing everything to 10,000? Is it your favourite number?

Comment: Why are you calling `++` on a `char[]`?? `arr[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++`.

Comment: This code is strange is a rather large number of ways - at the moment it doesn't compile let alone throw any `Exceptions`.

Comment: You have a loop `while(str != null) {` but inside it you never change str, so it will never end

Comment: In char[i]++ . I am actually setting a unique string to find anagrams of that particular key and I thought of limiting my file to 10000 words.

Comment: Setting the size of a _auto-expanding_ `Collection` to 10,000 doesn’t limit anything. If it’s just a unique key, why not use `int` or `long` or something more sensible - or the canonical (but slow) sorted word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is an infinite loop:

```
while(str != null) {
    char[] arr = new char[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        arr[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;              
    }
    String ns = new String(arr);
    if(map.containsKey(ns)){
        map.get(ns).add(str);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(10000);
        al.add(str);
        map.put(ns, al);
    }
}
```

because `str` is not altered within the loop body.  As a result, you end up repeatedly adding strings to an array list until you eventually run out of memory.

There are other problems with your code ... but this explains your OOME.

Comment: Can I know What are those Problems

Comment: Well, for a start, I can't see any code to generate anagrams.

Comment: char arr[26] represents 26 alphabets when I found that particular alphabet index increment it to one which replaces null character with a character after null and thus It generates a unique Key for a set of anagrams.

Comment: Oh.  I see.  So it isn't generating anagrams.  It is detecting them.